# Mac os - brew install unrar fails

Tags: macos, homebrew, unrar

I'm trying to run `brew install unrar` on mac os `Big Sur` and I'm getting the following error:

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Casks
Updated 1 cask.

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "unrar".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Please advise on how I can resolve this.

Comment: A search for "brew install unrar fails" brings up [Unrar has been removed, but I need unrar. Alternatives?](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/285) Maybe you could make an answer from that.

Comment: Thank you! it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 56):

Use `brew install rar` to install both the `rar` and `unrar` binaries.

Homebrew formulae: https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/rar

See cask source for details:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/r/rar.rb

Comment: given github [link](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/rar.rb) is broken

Answer (score 15):

Just use `brew install rar` instead of `brew install unrar`

#### For `rar` files

Try using Homebrew...

In a terminal type:

```
brew install rar
```

Now to use it just navigate to your file directory and type:

- To view the `rar` file:

```
unrar l <filename>
```

- To extract the `rar` file in the same location:

```
unrar x <filename>
```

- To extract the `rar` file in the desired location:

```
unrar x <filename>
```

In case you face any permission issue: **Developer cannot be verified**.
`'rar'` cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
**Follow this process:**
Open System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> General -> Click the lock to make changes.

---

#### For `zip` files

In the terminal (at `.zip` location):

```
unzip <filename>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the default `rar` formulae may cause permission errors in recent macOS versions. So you can install unrar using this custom formulae:

```
brew install carlocab/personal/unrar
```

See discussion about it here: [Unrar has been removed, but I need unrar. Alternatives?](https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/285).

Answer (score 3):

Go to mac's system settings/privacy&security/scroll down to security allow unrar app, you should see it as blocked.